# Solr: research in fields with relevance

Tags: solr, field, relevance

I'm using Solr 5.4.1 and all documents have the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" ?>
    <add >
        <doc >
            <field name ="title">US, Qatar Extend Talks OverFormer Taliban Detainees - Wall Street Journal</field>
            <field name ="date">2015-05-31T23:39:45Z</field>
            <field name ="description">The U.S. and Qatari governments have extended talks over the fate of five former Afghan Taliban prisoners ho were released from the Guantanamo Bay prison a year ago in exchange for an American soldier , U.S. officials said Sunday.</field>
        </doc >
</add >
```

As you can see from the structure, there are the fields `title` and `description`.

I would like to do some tests:

1) To search text in both fields as if they were one UNIQUE field.

2) To search text in both fields giving a different relevance weight to each field (e.g. 80% to `description` and 20% to `title`).

I know that we can use the parameter `qf` to specify where to search (fields); but I know that there is also the boolean operator `AND` to be specified in a parameter `q`.

Which one of the above mentioned tecniques can I use to do each tests?

Comment: There is something in Solr about copying fields to new field. I don't able to memorize it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to search both fields as a single field, add a new field (i.e. `title_description`) and use two `copyField` instructions to copy the content from both fields into the common field:
2. You can use `qf` with `description^4 title` to give any hits in description four times the weight of any hits in title. This will give you a 80/20 ratio, but remember that scoring is more complex than just simple percent weights between fields - the length of the content, the number of times the term is present, the position between fields (if using phrase boosting), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!! And what's the difference between using `q=title:some_text OR description:some_text` and `q=some_text & qf=description title`?

Comment: @MatteoBernardon You can use `debugQuery=true` to see for yourself if anything changes in the score calculations - my guess is that the latter is expanded to the former, so they should be close to (if not) identical.